# Two-way binding between service and controller without $scope.$watch. Is this a bad practice?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I've heard, that service should not be linked to scope variable in controller because view gains direct access to service. But i want to bind my scope variable to data that stored in service, and i want that variable to reflect all changes from service. I've read a lot of workaround, and in most of them were told to use $scope.$watch, if i want to watch service data from controller. I've wrote simple example without using of $scope.$watch, which is working exactly like i want, but i'm definitely not sure, can i use something like this, or it this a bad practice. I'm learning angular for about 2-3 days, and very need your advice:

html:

```
<div ng-controller="TestController">
    <p>Current value = {{ serviceData.getValue() }}</p>
    <input type="text" ng-model="newValue">
    <button ng-click="changeServiceData(newValue)">Change</button>
</div>
```

module.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
```

controller.js

```
app.controller('TestController', function($scope, testService){
    $scope.serviceData = testService.getPublicData();
    $scope.changeServiceData = function(newValue){
        testService.setValue(newValue);
    }
});
```

service.js

```
app.factory('testService', function(){
    var value = null;
    return {
        setValue: function(newValue){
            value = newValue;
        },
        getPublicData: function(){
            return {
                getValue: function(){
                    return value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Summarizing , view has access only to getters. To update data i'm using service, which i can inject in any controller, and all changes in service are reflected on controller, and on view.

**UPDATE:**
I have tried to change my factory like this:

```
app.factory('testService', function(){
var value = null;
return {
    setValue: function(newValue){
        value = newValue;
    },
    getValue: function(){
        return value;
    }
}
```

});

and assign getter to scope:

```
app.controller('TestController', function($scope, testService){
    $scope.value = testService.getValue();
    $scope.changeServiceData = function(newValue){
        testService.setValue(newValue);
    }
});
```

In this case, if i changing value in service from view using setter, value doesnt changing implictly in view, it doesnt reflect actual service data. Maybe you could explain such behaviour?

Comment: it's not a 2 way bindings since you only push the changes on click, and not any time the variable newValue changes. There's no problem with that, it's even better architecture and performances wise. Just curious about this getPublicData>getValue thing, why not having a service with just get/set (don't complexify things just for the purpose of doing so)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. About getPublicData: if i leave only getter in factory, without wrapping that getter in getPublicData then changes of value in service doesnt reflect on scope. I tried to do something like this: $scope.value = testService.getValue(). In this case, if i changing value in service using setter, i cant see changes in my view. Maybe you can explain me such behaviour?

Comment: @floribon Please check last update. Thanks!

Comment: I've added an answer where the service itself is bound to the scope, which is a common thing to do

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your update is almost right, if you've decided to use a service containing a variable it is meant to be shared accross modules and controllers.

What you need to do is only use this getter and setter now:

```
app.controller('TestController', function($scope, testService){
  $scope.testService = testService;
  $scope.newValue    = 'initial-value';
});
```

And in your HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="TestController">
  <p>Current value = {{ testService.getValue() }}</p>
  <input type="text" ng-model="newValue">
  <button ng-click="testService.setValue(newValue)">Change</button>
</div>
```

Now we still put value into the scope because apparently you want to update the service value only on click, so it need to be desynchronized from the service itself.

If you want to bind the service value directly into the ngModel of that input, you cannot use a getter but will have to use the variable directly:

```
<input ng-model="testService.value">
```

Or one last option is to propagate any changes made to newValue using the ngChange directive:

```
<input ng-model="newValue" ng-change="testService.setValue(newValue)">
```