# AngularJS - Update view on service data change

Tags: angularjs, typescript, model-view

I want my view to update when a new value is passed to the controller from my service.

service.js

```
function navigationTreeService($http, $q, perspectivesService) {
  return {
    getExtension: getExtension
  };

  function getExtension(){
       return extension;
  }
  function setExtension(value){
     extension = value;
  }
//
    }
```

controller.ts

```
angular.module('myModule').controller('ViewController',
   ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'userSessionService', 'navigationTreeService', '$http',
      function ($scope, $rootScope, userSessionService, navigationTreeService, $http) {
         'use strict';

        $scope.extensionNavi = navigationTreeService.getExtension();
}]);
```

view.html

```
<div class="extensionNavi" style="height: 50px; width: 400px;">
            {{extensionNavi}}
</div>
```

The following code only updates the view once, I want it to be updated every time a new value is set for the extension in the service.js. How can I achieve that? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Service doesn't provide a two-way binding like a controller. You will need to $watch your values or use [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33904608/two-way-binding-between-service-and-controller-without-scope-watch-is-this-a) to get and set values.

Answer (score 0):

if you share service values with controller, try to use object, like:

```
function navigationTreeService($http, $q, perspectivesService) {
    var model = {extension: undefined};

    function getExtension () {
        return model.extension;
    }

    function setExtension (value) {
            model.extension = value;
    }
    return {
            getExtension:getExtension
    };
}
```